# how to remove custom post type from wordpress url?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, custom-post-type

I have a wordpress website which is using the custom template with custom post types like landing and services.

Each post type have a specific slug in the url like this => (http://example.com/landing/landing-page-name)

I want to change this url (http://example.com/landing/landing-page-name) to this url (http://example.com/landing-page-name).

In fact I need to remove the [landing] phrase from the url. The important thing is that the [landing] is a custom post type in my posts table.

I have tested following solutions:

==> I have changed slug to '/' in rewrite property in register_post_type() --> It breaks the all of landings, posts and pages url (404)

==> I added 'with_front' => false to the rewrite property --> nothing changed

==> I tried to do this with RewriteRule in htaccess --> it did not work or give too many redirects error

I could not get a proper result.

Did anyone solve this problem before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to filter the permalink for your custom post type so that all published posts don't have the slug in their URLs:

```
function stackoverflow_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post ) {
    if ( 'landing' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'stackoverflow_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 2 );
```

At this point, trying to view the link would result in a 404 (Page Not Found) error. That's because WordPress only knows that Posts and Pages can have URLs like `domain.com/post-name/` or `domain.com/page-name/`. We need to teach it that our custom post type's posts can also have URLs like `domain.com/cpt-post-name/`.

```
function stackoverflow_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query( $query ) {
    // Return if this is not the main query.
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    // Return if this query doesn't match our very specific rewrite rule.
    if ( ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) || 2 !== count( $query->query ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Return if we're not querying based on the post name.
    if ( empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Add CPT to the list of post types WP will include when it queries based on the post name.
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'landing' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'stackoverflow_add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query' );
```

Comment: Hi @entreprenerds
Thank you for answer.
Could you tell me where I should use this codes?
In worpress core or in My template? and in which file?

Comment: I don't know how to use these codes.
Could you help me please?
@entreprenerds

Comment: Sorry - you should just need to paste them both into your `functions.php` file. The `function {..}` code defines the new function we want to use, and then the `add_filter` and `add_action` commands tell WordPress when to use them.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, it's 100% working for single custom post type and multiple post types. Add this class in functions.php file in your theme or create a separate file and import it into functions.php

```
class remove_cpt_base {
    var $plugin_admin_page;
    static $instance = null;

    static public function init() {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function __construct() {
        add_action('plugins_loaded', array($this, 'plugins_loaded'));

        $this->rcptb_selected = get_option('rcptb_selected', array());
        $this->rcptb_selected_keys = array_keys($this->rcptb_selected);

        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'plugin_menu_link'));
        add_filter('post_type_link', array($this, 'remove_slug'), 10, 3);
        add_action('template_redirect', array($this, 'auto_redirect_old'), 1);
        add_action('pre_get_posts', array($this, 'handle_cpts'), 1);
    }

    function plugins_loaded() {
        load_plugin_textdomain('remove_cpt_base', FALSE, basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/languages/');
    }

    function filter_plugin_actions($links, $file) {
        $settings_link = '<a href="options-general.php?page=' . basename(__FILE__) . '">' . __('Settings') . '</a>';
        array_unshift($links, $settings_link);
        return $links;
    }

    function plugin_menu_link() {
        $this->plugin_admin_page = add_submenu_page(
            'options-general.php',
            __('Remove CPT base', 'remove_cpt_base'),
            __('Remove CPT base', 'remove_cpt_base'),
            'manage_options',
            basename(__FILE__),
            array($this, 'admin_options_page')
        );
        add_filter('plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), array($this, 'filter_plugin_actions'), 10, 2);
    }

    function admin_options_page() {
        if (get_current_screen()->id != $this->plugin_admin_page) {
            return;
        }

        global $wp_post_types;?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2><?php _e('Remove base slug from url for these custom post types:', 'remove_cpt_base')?></h2><?php
if (isset($_POST['rcptb_selected_sent'])) {

            if (!isset($_POST['rcptb_alternation']) || !is_array($_POST['rcptb_alternation'])) {
                $alternation = array();
            } else {
                $alternation = $_POST['rcptb_alternation'];
            }

            if (!isset($_POST['rcptb_selected']) || !is_array($_POST['rcptb_selected'])) {
                $this->rcptb_selected = array();
            } else {
                $this->rcptb_selected = $_POST['rcptb_selected'];
            }

            foreach ($this->rcptb_selected as $post_type => $active) {
                $this->rcptb_selected[$post_type] = isset($alternation[$post_type]) ? 1 : 0;
            }

            $this->rcptb_selected_keys = array_keys($this->rcptb_selected);

            update_option('rcptb_selected', $this->rcptb_selected, 'no');
            echo '<div class="below-h2 updated"><p>' . __('Settings saved.') . '</p></div>';
            flush_rewrite_rules();
        }?>
            <br>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="rcptb_selected_sent" value="1">
                <table class="widefat" style="width:auto">
                    <tbody><?php
foreach ($wp_post_types as $type => $custom_post) {
            if ($custom_post->_builtin == false) {?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="rcptb_selected[<?php echo $custom_post->name ?>]" value="1" <?php echo isset($this->rcptb_selected[$custom_post->name]) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                                            <?php echo $custom_post->label ?> (<?php echo $custom_post->name ?>)
                                        </label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="rcptb_alternation[<?php echo $custom_post->name ?>]" value="1" <?php echo isset($this->rcptb_selected[$custom_post->name]) && $this->rcptb_selected[$custom_post->name] == 1 ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
                                            <?php _e('alternation', 'remove_cpt_base')?>
                                        </label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr><?php
}
        }?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <p><?php _e('* if your custom post type children return error 404, then try alternation mode', 'remove_cpt_base')?></p>
                <hr>
                <p class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save')?>">
                </p>
            </form>
        </div><?php
}

    function remove_slug($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
        global $wp_post_types;
        foreach ($wp_post_types as $type => $custom_post) {
            if ($custom_post->_builtin == false && $type == $post->post_type && isset($this->rcptb_selected[$custom_post->name])) {
                $custom_post->rewrite['slug'] = trim($custom_post->rewrite['slug'], '/');
                $permalink = str_replace('/' . $custom_post->rewrite['slug'] . '/', '/', $permalink);
            }
        }
        return $permalink;
    }

    function get_current_url() {
        $REQUEST_URI = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');
        $real_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $real_url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $REQUEST_URI;
        return $real_url;
    }

    function handle_cpts($query) {
        // make sure it's main query on frontend
        if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && !$query->get('queried_object_id')) {
            // conditions investigated after many tests
            if ($query->is_404() || $query->get('pagename') || $query->get('attachment') || $query->get('name') || $query->get('category_name')) {
                // test both site_url and home_url
                $web_roots = array();
                $web_roots[] = site_url();
                if (site_url() != home_url()) {
                    $web_roots[] = home_url();
                }
                // polylang fix
                if (function_exists('pll_home_url')) {
                    if (site_url() != pll_home_url()) {
                        $web_roots[] = pll_home_url();
                    }
                }

                foreach ($web_roots as $web_root) {
                    // get clean current URL path
                    $path = $this->get_current_url();
                    $path = str_replace($web_root, '', $path);
                    // fix missing slash
                    if (substr($path, 0, 1) != '/') {
                        $path = '/' . $path;
                    }
                    // test for posts
                    $post_data = get_page_by_path($path, OBJECT, 'post');
                    if (!($post_data instanceof WP_Post)) {
                        // test for pages
                        $post_data = get_page_by_path($path);
                        if (!is_object($post_data)) {
                            // test for selected CPTs
                            $post_data = get_page_by_path($path, OBJECT, $this->rcptb_selected_keys);
                            if (is_object($post_data)) {
                                // maybe name with ancestors is needed
                                $post_name = $post_data->post_name;
                                if ($this->rcptb_selected[$post_data->post_type] == 1) {
                                    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post_data->ID);
                                    foreach ($ancestors as $ancestor) {
                                        $post_name = get_post_field('post_name', $ancestor) . '/' . $post_name;
                                    }
                                }
                                // get CPT slug
                                $query_var = get_post_type_object($post_data->post_type)->query_var;
                                // alter query
                                $query->is_404 = 0;
                                $query->tax_query = NULL;
                                $query->is_attachment = 0;
                                $query->is_category = 0;
                                $query->is_archive = 0;
                                $query->is_tax = 0;
                                $query->is_page = 0;
                                $query->is_single = 1;
                                $query->is_singular = 1;
                                $query->set('error', NULL);
                                unset($query->query['error']);
                                $query->set('page', '');
                                $query->query['page'] = '';
                                $query->set('pagename', NULL);
                                unset($query->query['pagename']);
                                $query->set('attachment', NULL);
                                unset($query->query['attachment']);
                                $query->set('category_name', NULL);
                                unset($query->query['category_name']);
                                $query->set('post_type', $post_data->post_type);
                                $query->query['post_type'] = $post_data->post_type;
                                $query->set('name', $post_name);
                                $query->query['name'] = $post_name;
                                $query->set($query_var, $post_name);
                                $query->query[$query_var] = $post_name;

                                break;
                            } else {
                                // deeper matching
                                global $wp_rewrite;
                                // test all selected CPTs
                                foreach ($this->rcptb_selected_keys as $post_type) {
                                    // get CPT slug and its length
                                    $query_var = get_post_type_object($post_type)->query_var;
                                    // test all rewrite rules
                                    foreach ($wp_rewrite->rules as $pattern => $rewrite) {
                                        // test only rules for this CPT
                                        if (strpos($pattern, $query_var) !== false) {
                                            if (strpos($pattern, '(' . $query_var . ')') === false) {
                                                preg_match_all('#' . $pattern . '#', '/' . $query_var . $path, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                                            } else {
                                                preg_match_all('#' . $pattern . '#', $query_var . $path, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                                            }

                                            if (count($matches) !== 0 && isset($matches[0])) {
                                                // build URL query array
                                                $rewrite = str_replace('index.php?', '', $rewrite);
                                                parse_str($rewrite, $url_query);
                                                foreach ($url_query as $key => $value) {
                                                    $value = (int) str_replace(array('$matches[', ']'), '', $value);
                                                    if (isset($matches[0][$value])) {
                                                        $value = $matches[0][$value];
                                                        $url_query[$key] = $value;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                // test new path for selected CPTs
                                                if (isset($url_query[$query_var])) {
                                                    $post_data = get_page_by_path('/' . $url_query[$query_var], OBJECT, $this->rcptb_selected_keys);
                                                    if (is_object($post_data)) {
                                                        // alter query
                                                        $query->is_404 = 0;
                                                        $query->tax_query = NULL;
                                                        $query->is_attachment = 0;
                                                        $query->is_category = 0;
                                                        $query->is_archive = 0;
                                                        $query->is_tax = 0;
                                                        $query->is_page = 0;
                                                        $query->is_single = 1;
                                                        $query->is_singular = 1;
                                                        $query->set('error', NULL);
                                                        unset($query->query['error']);
                                                        $query->set('page', '');
                                                        $query->query['page'] = '';
                                                        $query->set('pagename', NULL);
                                                        unset($query->query['pagename']);
                                                        $query->set('attachment', NULL);
                                                        unset($query->query['attachment']);
                                                        $query->set('category_name', NULL);
                                                        unset($query->query['category_name']);
                                                        $query->set('post_type', $post_data->post_type);
                                                        $query->query['post_type'] = $post_data->post_type;
                                                        $query->set('name', $url_query[$query_var]);
                                                        $query->query['name'] = $url_query[$query_var];
                                                        // solve custom rewrites, pagination, etc.
                                                        foreach ($url_query as $key => $value) {
                                                            if ($key != 'post_type' && substr($value, 0, 8) != '$matches') {
                                                                $query->set($key, $value);
                                                                $query->query[$key] = $value;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        break 3;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function auto_redirect_old() {
        global $post;
        if (!is_preview() && is_single() && is_object($post) && isset($this->rcptb_selected[$post->post_type])) {
            $new_url = get_permalink();
            $real_url = $this->get_current_url();
            if (substr_count($new_url, '/') != substr_count($real_url, '/') && strstr($real_url, $new_url) == false) {
                remove_filter('post_type_link', array($this, 'remove_slug'), 10);
                $old_url = get_permalink();
                add_filter('post_type_link', array($this, 'remove_slug'), 10, 3);
                $fixed_url = str_replace($old_url, $new_url, $real_url);
                wp_redirect($fixed_url, 301);
            }
        }
    }
}

function rcptb_remove_plugin_options() {
    delete_option('rcptb_selected');
}

add_action('init', array('remove_cpt_base', 'init'), 99);
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules');
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'rcptb_remove_plugin_options');
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Solution by entreprenerds did not work for my multisite and pages are displaying 404 even though I tried to fix that code. 
I wish I could upvote this 50 times.

Comment: After trying everything else given here and on a few other sites, this works flawlessly. I'm wondering why this one is not an accepted answer. Should be upvoted much more.

Comment: You just copy paste source code from my plugin... that's not very cool... you should install my plugin, because there are updates and changes in meantime...

Answer (score 1):

To the rewrite you just have to change your current slug from ‘cpt-slug’ to ‘/’ and the with-front: ‘false’. And done, you just resave permalinks and the url shouldn’t display the cpt slug anymore.

Comment: As @saeed stated, this breaks other page types, including other custom post types.

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue and came across this answer and none of the above mentioned solution works so tried different plugins and the best which worked, removed base slug and solved 404 error try [Remove CPT base](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-cpt-base/)