# How can I replace a custom-post-type with a custom post category in permalink without getting a 404 in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I'm a wordpress newbie. I will try to describe my problem in the clearest way possible.

I'm trying to do two things here:

1. Remove CPT from a permalink.
2. Add a custom taxonomy type where it used to be the CPT in the permalink.

Permalinks on site used to be like this:

```
http://example.com/custom-post-type/post-name
```

I managed to remove the CPT from the permalink based on this:
[how to remove custom post type from wordpress url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58583516/how-to-remove-custom-post-type-from-wordpress-url)

Then I modify my code to add the custom taxonomy type to the permalink to be like this:

```
http://example.com/post-category/post-name
```

This is my code:

```
function remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post ) {

    if ( 'custom-post-type-name' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
        $post_tags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'custom-post-type-name-category');
        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/' . $post_tags[0]->slug . '/', $post_link );
    }
    
    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_cpt_slug', 10, 2 );

function add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query( $query ) {
    // Return if this is not the main query.
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    // Return if this query doesn't match our very specific rewrite rule.
    if ( ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) || 2 !== count( $query->query ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Return if we're not querying based on the post name.
    if ( empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Add CPT to the list of post types WP will include when it queries based on the post name.
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'custom-post-type-name' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_cpt_post_names_to_main_query' );
```

This worked but now every post from my CPT gives a 404. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you wanting to change the URL for only the CPT? Is there a reason you can't just change the Permalink settings?

Comment: Yes. I want to change the url for a specific custom post type. I tried to use this plugin: https://es-mx.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/ but it gave me the same result. The permalinks were changed but the pages gave me a 404. I must add that I'm also using a custom taxonomy type.

Comment: I see. I'm not really sure but [this may help you](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/).